# Co-linking a File array with a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a little issue with linking File and String arrays together..... I want to match each element of the File array to its corresponding number in the String array, E.g (Match word[1] to answer[1]) I don't have an idea about that.... thanks for the help!

```
private static File[] word = 

    { new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\audio.mp3"), 
        new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\baby.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\board.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\bomb.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\gym.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\football.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\school.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\keyboard.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\computer.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\name.mp3"), 
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\lady.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\church.mp3"), 
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\sport.mp3"), 
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\beauty.mp3"), 
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\radio.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\prince.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\hearing.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\worship.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\song.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\flower.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\water.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\nature.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\goal.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\manifest.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\election.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\number.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\sentence.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\movie.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\sound.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\teacher.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\speed.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\time.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\debate.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\video.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\music.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\phone.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\mountain.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\drink.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\market.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\broom.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\help.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\picture.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\princess.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\cake.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\river.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\dance.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\rely.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\level.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\wealth.mp3"),
    new File ("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\surname.mp3") };

    private String []answer = {"audio", "baby", "board", "bomb", "gym", "football", "school", "keyboard", "computer", "name" ,
            "lady", "church", "sport", "beauty", "radio", "prince", "hearing", "worship", "song", "flower", "water", "nature", "goal" ,
            "manifest", "election", "number", "sentence", "movie", "sound", "teacher", "speed", "time", "debate", "video", "music", 
            "phone", "drink", "market", "broom", "help", "picture", "princess", "cake", "river", "dance", "rely", "level", "wealth", "surname"};

JButton click = new JButton();

public class Beginner(){

click = new JButton("1");

click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent x){

    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to match `word[1]` to `answer[1]` you .... *ehhhh* .... well, you just did. They have the *same* index value. That's how they are matched. What was your problem again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better of using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
Map<String, File> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put("audio", new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Word Pronunciation\\audio.mp3");
// etc...
```

and then get the value by using:

```
File file = mapping.get("audio");
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 way would be

```
Map<String, File> mapping = IntStream.range(0, word.length)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> answer[i], i -> word[i]));
```

to link your arrays.